# Android progress Dialog only updating Message , not the bar and the lines

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am going to implement the FTP download function. It works but when it comes to reporting the progress, I have only found that only the message changes but not the numbers and the bar changing

I have screen captured as below

[image]

The below is my code:

```
public void buttonExit(View v) {
    System.exit(1); 
}

public void doClick(View v){

    //ftp

    filename = null;
    filename = "giant.mp4";

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("EOrder");
    pd.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setMax(100);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setProgress(0);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setTitle("EOrder");
    ad.setMessage("Download Finish");
    ad.setNeutralButton("OK", null);

    new FTPDownload().execute(filename);
}

class FTPDownload extends AsyncTask<String , String , Void>{

    boolean running = true;

    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();    
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
    String reportDate = formatter.format(today);


    String fileAndroid = reportDate + "_" + filename;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("******", "Background thread starting......"); 

        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

        try {
            Log.d("tag" , "arrived");

            client.connect("newaswrissssing.win5.siteonlinetest.com");
            boolean successLogin = client.login("newaswrissssing", "newaswrissssing2014cap!");


            if(successLogin){
                client.changeWorkingDirectory("dummy");
                Log.d("tag" , "success");
                long fileSize = getFileSize(client , params[0]);
                client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                File instanceRecordDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TVB_Movie");

                if(!instanceRecordDirectory.exists()){
                    instanceRecordDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                File instanceRecord = new File(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileAndroid);

                if(!instanceRecord.exists()){
                    instanceRecord.createNewFile();
                }

                BufferedOutputStream desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(instanceRecord.getAbsolutePath()),8*1024);


                InputStream in = client.retrieveFileStream(params[0]);

                Log.d("as" , String.valueOf(in));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                long total = 0;

                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    total += len1; //total = total + len1
                    Log.d("aDDs" , String.valueOf(in));
                    publishProgress("" + (int)((total*100)/fileSize));
                    desFileStream.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }

                desFileStream.flush();
                desFileStream.close();

                client.completePendingCommand();
                in.close();

            }else{
                Log.d("tag" , "sosad");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.logout();
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);           
        Log.d("progress","values: "+progress[0]);
        pd.incrementProgressBy(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        pd.setMessage("Downloading file... Progress at " + progress[0] + "%");      
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
          ad.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

Would you please tell me what other steps to do besides using `pd.incrementProgressBy(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));` or `setProgress`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your ProgressDialog should not be intederminate. You should call `setIndeterminate` with `false` instead of `true`

```
pd.setIndeterminate(false);
```

and you should use `setProgress` instead of `incrementProgressBy`

Comment: are there any methods to enhance the performance of AsyncTask ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati AsyncTask is basically a thread. the time of its excutions is strictly related to the code inside doInBackground. More the code is complex more time its exectuions will require

Comment: That means if I am tring to increase to the buffer size but less than 9000 according to the maximum MTU  , I am trying to enhance the performance ?