# ProgressBar does not work - Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-progressbar

I have a code where the values of the accelerometer should correspond to the progress of the progress bar. I have attached my code below. Even though I use setProgress, the progress bar just shows the normal 'buffering thing and does not reflect progress as per what I want it to show.

My java code:

```
//package comes here

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AccelerometerControl extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView xText, yText, zText;
    private Sensor mySensor;
    private SensorManager SM;
    ProgressBar fd,bk,rt,lt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer_control);
        SM = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mySensor = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        SM.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        xText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        yText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        zText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        fd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.up_magnitude);
        bk = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.down_magnitude);
        rt = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.right_magnitude);
        lt = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.left_magnitude);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        xText.setText("X: " + event.values[0]);
        yText.setText("Y: " + event.values[1]);
        zText.setText("Z: " + event.values[2]);

        float x=event.values[0]*16.67f;
        float y=event.values[1]*16.67f;
        float z=event.values[2]*16.67f;
        int percentX = (int) x;
        int percentY = (int) y;
        fd.setProgress(percentX);
        rt.setProgress(percentY);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

}
```

My Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ControllerActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/up"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/up"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/down" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/up"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/up"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BTID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:text="Bluetooth ID" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/right_magnitude"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/up"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/up"
        android:indeterminate="false"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/left_magnitude"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/up"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/up"
        android:indeterminate="false"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/up_magnitude"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/down_magnitude"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="X axis accel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Y axis accel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Z axis accel" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

(I will be making changes once I get the progress bars (progress circles) working.)

Comment: Not sure but.. You need to set `android:indeterminate="false"` to `progressbar`.

Comment: Tried that... doesn't work

Comment: does your textviews show the correct values?

Comment: Not sure but I think Clear Cookies, solves problem@Shlok Jhawar

Comment: Can you update your question with the layout.xml?

Comment: @MehranZamani yes, they do

Comment: @ShlokJhawar   check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272062/android-progress-dialog-only-updating-message-not-the-bar-and-the-lines)

Comment: Tried that out too, nothing works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you haven't set the progress bar style correctly. Add `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` Update all your progressbar layout as follows:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/up_magnitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
/>
```

The above code will create horizontal progress bar. If you want to create circular progress bar, you can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it)

Comment: I need a circular progress bar, where I can set the progress fill (For example, 50% corresponds to 180 degrees)

Comment: check the updated answer. You can implement the circular bar but you need to do some customization to make it work as per your expectation